# Why is my request working without requesting a new XSRF token?

Tags: java, gwt, csrf

Is it enough to request *one* XSRF token from the server and reuse it over the whole session **or** should I request for each protect-worthy action like save, edit or delete a *new* XSRF token first and *then* perform the actual request?

This question arises because I don't understand why my XSRF protected request is working even though I am not requesting a new one:

```
public void saveName(Long shopId, Long languageId, String name, OnSuccessCallback<String> success, OnFailureCallback failure) {

    Request.<String> doRequest(this.shopService,

            asyncCallback -> {
                this.shopService.saveName(shopId, languageId, name, asyncCallback);
            }, 

            (String result) -> {
                // ..
                success.onSuccess(result);
            }, failure);
}
```

Here `Request#doRequest()` will simply perform a request but won't ask for a new XSRF token first. I would have to change it to `XsrfRequest#doRequest()` which does the same thing basically but will request a XSRF token *first*.

The thing is that `saveName()` is supposed to be protected:

```
@XsrfProtect
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("shop")
public interface ShopServlet extends RemoteService {
    // ..
    String saveName(Long shopId, Long languageId, String name);
}
```

**Please note:** Before `saveName()` is getting called there are several other requests of which some of them already get XSRF tokens. But since I can save a new name without requesting a new one I have the feeling that the previous requested token is getting reused here. Is this okay that way?

Another thing I noticed is if I add `@NoXsrfProtect` to `saveName()`

```
@NoXsrfProtect
String saveName(Long restaurantId, Long languageId, String name);
```

that the request will still contain XSRF token information:

```
7|2|9|http://localhost:8080/app/|424F33664CAA93E2F8A4A94C57DA5827|com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.XsrfToken/4254043109|..ShopServlet|saveName|java.lang..
```

Why is the token being sent here even though the method is declared as `@NoXsrfProtect`?

Could somebody clarify this to me? I don't want to make any mistakes - especially in security related matters..

Answer (score 0):

> Is it enough to request one XSRF token from the server and reuse it over the whole session or should I request for each protect-worthy action like save, edit or delete a new XSRF token first and then perform the actual request?

Lets ignore GWT RPC's built-in XSRF protection for a moment and look at the title question and this remark: What is XSRF and how do we protect against it?

### What is XSRF

XSRF stands for Cross Site Request Forgery - the idea is that a malicious site could somehow forge a request, and force one of our users to correctly send it to our application, as if they had intended to do it themselves. For example, if all it took to transfer money from one bank account to another was

```
GET /transfer?from=me&to=attacker&amount=10000USD
```

then an attacker could very simply make a request to our server as an image, css, or js file, from their own site:

```
<img src="https://securebank.com/transfer?from=me&to=attacker&amount=10000USD" />
```

Setting aside other details ("okay, that works for a GET, how did they manage to send a POST to my GWT RPC service?"), lets look at the idea of a XSRF "token" preventing this attack: what is it that a friendly client knows or can do, that an attacker cannot know or do?

### Mitigation

The idea is that the client should have a way to indicate to the server that it is trusted - that it knows something which only a valid client could know, which indicates that the user is willing to make the specified action. One option is to require the user to perform a captcha, in such a way that the action cannot be scripted by the attacking site, and the user must consciously perform. Another option is to make some data available to a real/trusted client, such as cookies (that can only be read from a page loaded on the same domain), or as part of the HTML page as it loads or some other request (which might be possible to be sent by some other means, but the results can't be read).

OWASP refers to this latter piece of data as a ["Synchronizer Token"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens):

> The synchronizer token pattern requires the generating of random "challenge" tokens that are associated with the user's current session. [...] When the user wishes to invoke these sensitive operations, the HTTP request should include this challenge token. It is then the responsibility of the server application to verify the existence and correctness of this token.

So, in this case, we could write some value to a cookie so that only the client can see it, and the client can then use this to generate a token. That token then should be passed to the server on each request that must be verified. But from this description, we see that it isn't necessarily important to only have one valid token at a time.

### But if the attacker can get an XSS, they can just read the token and force the request again! Or MitM!

That's true, but if they have an XSS, then *any* request that your own JS can make, the attack can make as well. You've lost, pack up shop, time to go home. Likewise if they own the connection between the user and application and can read and write at will. XSRF protection isn't a magic wand that solves all problems, its a specific attack, and only needs to be addressed on its own: a lock in your home isn't considered faulty if the window can be broken.

### Okay, back to GWT

So how does GWT do this? As you've noted, the `@XsrfProtect` annotation marks a service type as needing to be checked on the server. The client then must request a token, and then make sure the client's service is aware of that token for future requests.

So how does the server generate a token? The `XsrfTokenServiceServlet` RPC service on the server generates the token, as part of each call to the server, as you've observed, `XsrfProtectedServiceServlet.validateXsrfToken` then verifies that this is correct. If you wanted custom behavior, you'd have to modify each side of that system, and you *could* build it to invalidate each token once it is used, but this is not the default (nor, according to OWASP, is it encouraged).

> Another thing I noticed is if I add @NoXsrfProtect to saveName()...

Note that `validateXsrfToken` is only called in one place in GWT, from in `AbstractXsrfProtectedServiceServlet`:

```
@Override
protected void onAfterRequestDeserialized(RPCRequest rpcRequest) {
  if (shouldValidateXsrfToken(rpcRequest.getMethod())) {
    validateXsrfToken(rpcRequest.getRpcToken(), rpcRequest.getMethod());
  }
}
```

The method `shouldValidateXsrfToken` then checks if the method expressly has the protection disabled. If so, it will return false, and no check will be performed. But when building up the `RPCRequest` object, `RPC.decodeRequest` always appends the token, even if that token happens to be null:

```
  RpcToken rpcToken = null;
  if (streamReader.hasFlags(AbstractSerializationStream.FLAG_RPC_TOKEN_INCLUDED)) {
    // Read the RPC token
    rpcToken = (RpcToken) streamReader.deserializeValue(RpcToken.class);
  }
```

So if the client is configured to send the token, it will always be sent, though the server might ignore it.

### More reading:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF) and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
- http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html